# how to change in below url redirect script

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url redirect script that works very well, but i want some change in it.

when i redirect outgoing link then at the end of redirected url i got something like '**#lcinside**'

example

`http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36139836/unknown.html?urlc=http://imgur.com/`

goes to

`http://imgur.com/#lcinside`

but i want to put `#lcinside` before url start.

example

`#lcinsidehttp://imgur.com`

i want to put adf url redirect link instead of `#lcinside`.

how can i put `#lcinside` before url .

below is script.

please help me.

```
<script>
function gup(sName)
{
    sName = sName.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var sRegEx = "[\\?&]" + sName + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regEx = new RegExp(sRegEx);
    var aResult = regEx.exec(window.location.href);
    if(aResult == null)
    {
      return "";
    }
    else
    {
       return aResult[1];
    }
}
if(gup("urlc") != "")
{
    window.location = gup("urlc").replace("lcamp", "&") + "#lcinside";
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are wanting to do is possible, as #lcinside is not a valid protocol and will likely not trigger a redirect.

Perhaps you can explain the use case a little bit more and we can try to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: i know that, when i know how to put  #lcinside before url then i will remove it and put http://blankrefer.com/? instead of #lcinside.

Comment: just simple question what type of change in script make  #lcinside before redirected url

Comment: when you click below link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36139836/unknown.html?urlc=http://imgur.com/ it will give output like http://imgur.com/#lcinside and i want output like #lcinsidehttp://imgur.com/ whether it will redirect or not. redirection is not important

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to scrub the referrer, maybe you should use meta refresh

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://imgur.com/#lcinside">`